# How to extend in css the right vertical div line when there is a horizontal div line next to it like down below?

Tags: html, css

```
The code may be missing but help me fix it.
```

Use an editor and explain to me how to extend this down below  in images...
PLEASE HELP ME what properties or what can I do to extend justa a a line

[Image of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH4Ed.png)

```
<html>
    <div class="new2">
            <div class="new1">
    
            </div>
    
    <style>
    .new1{
      background-color: #ccc;
    width: 1px;
    height: 2000px;
    margin-left: 1200px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    float: right;
    
    }
    
    .new2 {
     background-color: #ccc;
      width: 1000px;
    height: 1px;
    margin-top:300px;
    float: left;
    }
    
    </style>
    </html>
```

Comment: extend what?  Question as stated makes no sense.

Comment: I recommend you write a jsfiddle.com, showing what you have already tried. You can make it look like your image, with the red line not quite as you want it, and then explain a bit better what it is you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

is something like this what you had in mind?

```css
.short {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.tall {
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: solid 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='tall'>
  <div class='short'></div><br>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x300.png">
</div>
```